# WCF filestream queue

Tags: c#, wcf, file-io, msmq

I am trying to create a web-service, that would be able to receive a file from client, process it (for example open the txt file, change the values somehow etc.) and then provide it to client after it is processed.

The things I have done so far is that I have a service+host and WinForm application for client, that is able to choose file, send it and then get the list of files that are stored on served and manualy download selected file back (Im using WCF streaming).

Next thing I need to do is create some sort of queue - it would be nice to have the file download process from server automated. But there is also possibility, that before the server manage to process the file from client, the client could go (intetionaly or not) offline and thus the server would not be able to send the file back.

I checked some manuals and tutorial and found out, that there is a built-in technology called MSMQ, that could be used in WCF - it simply put the data in queue, if the client/server is not avaiable atm and attempt to send them later.
The only problem is, that in each manual, they are working only with methods (they put methods call in queue) but not with files.

My question is - is it possible to implement MSMQ with file streaming somehow? Or should I choose different approach?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should try sending file in array of bytes to MSMQ service.

Comment: I could try it, but will MSMQ be able to handle big files? My colleague told me, that the size of files we will be processing could be up to 100MB each.

Comment: Queues aren't meant to handle files, they are meant to handle messages. If you have a 100MB message you are doing it wrong. What are you trying to do and why do you think you need queues? Are you sure you aren't confusing queues with synchronization services like Dropbox and Onedrive?

Comment: Well the goal was to send the processed file back to client as soon as client is connected and the file processed. But maybe MSMQ or queues overall is not good solution - I know there are used for messages, I was just wondering, whether they could be used for file streaming as well :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web service shouild save the uploaded image to a directory on your server and then return a JobID to the webpage.  The web service method could also then post a message using System.Messaging with that JobID (and all relevant file info, etc) to an MSMQ queue.  You can then write a WCF service that uses MSMQIntegration Binding to listen to this queue. You would write a method in this service that would perform whatever operations you wish to perform on the file, and the method would automatically take the message off the queue, or if the service was offline, the messages would remain there until this service is back online.

Does this address your needs?

:) David

Comment: Thank you for you answer David. So basicaly I will have one service, that will handle downloading/uploading files and then second service, that will be informed by first service, that there is file ready to be processed, right? I just have to think how to implement automatic file download process to clients computer in these services - because if Im not mistaken, clients computer should send next message that it is ready to download the file back (so the server should send any message trying to reach client first)

Comment: You might want to have a database table, that records the job and its current status. When web service first uploads file it could enter new job in table, with a Pending status. When MSMQ service finishes processing the file, it could set Status to Complete. Your web service could also have a couple of utility methods, such as checking the Status of a Job, by JobID, and assuming status is Complete, would allow the client to download the completed file by passing the JobID.

Comment: That is a very good idea with keeping the job status and id in database table...it should be easy enough to handle. Im beginner in C# and WCF, but I think after few more tutorials, I should be able to implement it. Thank you for your time and answer. Have a nice day.